# Is there an app that bulk transfers camera photos to emails?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, photos, camera

Is there an app that allows us to bulk transfer **full resolution** camera photos to our emails?

For example, if I select 100 photos, the app will automatically email me all  the selected photos.

Currently, I'm using the default "Photos" app but it only allows up to [**5 pictures** per transfer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/74091/6533), which means we would have to repeat the same manual action 20 times just to send a hundred photos.

(Please do not say use the USB cable, because I need the transfer to be done via the internet.)

Comment: why not just use iPhoto?

Comment: @Tetsujin, Do you mean the default "Photos" app?

Comment: Image Capture is a much more efficient method of transferring photos: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH17894

Comment: @cksum, I'm also using that too. But being tied to the house computer, it often isn't convenient, **nor possible** for travellers.

Comment: The problem is email size is limited.  This is why you can't select 100 pic at once.  You must stay within email size limits.

Comment: I cannot fathom why you wish to email gigabytes of pictures to yourself. Dropbox provides online storage that can be shared and accessed by any operating system. It also allows for batch uploading of images. iCloud Photo Library also allows the sharing of photos between iOS, OS X, PC, and the web. AirDrop too can transfer photos easily. The problem is you I'm afraid. You've adopted an archaic strategy that was ridiculous even back in 1999. I wholeheartedly suggest you find alternative strategies to deal with your photos. This question won't likely be answered for that very reason.

Comment: @cksum, It doesn't need to be email, but it needs to be **via the internet**. Email is not the final storage location of course, it's just a stopgap holder while I move the photos from gmail to my respective gdrive folders. Storing gigabytes in email is impossible in 1999 but now it's possible up to 10 TB with gmail. I **am** finding alternative strategies to move photos from iphone to gdrive, which is the whole point of the question in the first place, do feel free to post answers if you know of good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the Photo app you can select and copy as many images as you want, can't you?

Have you tried copying and pasting into the standard email app?

Comment: It doesn't work, the mail app will complain of error. Emails are still limited to 25 MB.